# how to add points to stacked barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, ggplotly

I would like to add points (the variable nb species) on my already
existing chart. I tried to add the points with the function `geom_point` but unfortunately i have this error:

> `"Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".`

You will find below my data and my code.

```
  structure(list(SOUNAME = c("BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)"
), year_month = c("2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", 
"2014-06", "2014-06", "2014-06", "2014-06", "2014-07", "2014-07", 
"2014-07", "2014-07"), pre_type = c("NONE", "HEAVY", "LIGHT", 
"MEDIUM", "NONE", "HEAVY", "LIGHT", "MEDIUM", "NONE", "HEAVY", 
"LIGHT", "MEDIUM"), pre_value = c(3, 6, 20, 2, 16, 2, 9, 2, 3, 
3, 22, 3), tem_type = c("V_COLD", "COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM", "V_COLD", 
"COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM", "V_COLD", "COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM"), 
    tem_value = c(0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 24, 6, 0, 0, 23, 8, 0), nb_species = c("NA", 
    "3", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L)), .Names = c("SOUNAME", "year_month", "pre_type", "pre_value", 
"tem_type", "tem_value", "nb_species", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data = complet_b, aes(x = x, y = pre_value, fill = pre_type), stat = "identity") +
          scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:3, labels=unique(complet_b$year_month)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.3) +
          xlab("date") + ylab ("Number of days of precipitation") +
          ggtitle("Precipitation per month") + labs(fill = "Frequency") +
          geom_bar(data=complet_b,aes(x=x+0.4, y=tem_value, fill=tem_type), width=0.3, stat = "identity") +
          xlab("date") + ylab("Number of days of temperature") +
          ggtitle("Temperature per month") + labs(fill = "Frequency")
```

Thanks a lot for take time to help me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column `nb_species` is in character format, convert it to numeric and you are good to go.

A quick `str(complet_b)` would tell you that your column format.

```
complet_b$nb_species <- as.numeric(complet_b$nb_species)
```

Here is your code and plot with the dot present in the graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = complet_b, aes(x = x, y = pre_value, fill = pre_type), stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:3, labels=unique(complet_b$year_month)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.3) +
  xlab("date") + ylab ("Number of days of precipitation") +
  ggtitle("Precipitation per month") + labs(fill = "Frequency") +
  geom_bar(data=complet_b,aes(x=x+0.4, y=tem_value, fill=tem_type), width=0.3, stat = "identity") +
  xlab("date") + ylab("Number of days of temperature") +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y= nb_species)) +
  ggtitle("Temperature per month") + labs(fill = "Frequency")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is it possible to center / move the point between the two columns? Similarly for the abscissa axis?

Comment: @ElodieP., Please accept(Green check mark)/upvote  the solution if it solved the problem, On moving the point,You can shift the dot , but here the value of this point is 3 on `2014-05`,so unless you change the value you can't move it. You can see your data. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, I'm new, I had not seen ...
is it possible to move the chest, not up or down but more to the right?

Comment: @ElodieP., its dependent on your x axis, if this value is present on the row where date is 2014-06 , it would have been in the centre, Like I said, its totally dependent on your input data, Try plotting in a piece of paper you will understand it more. However, there might be a another way, but its very unlikely

Comment: Yes but I do not understand why the point is put on the barplot pre_type, and not in the middle ..? (between the barplot tem and a barplot pre)

Comment: @Elodie P. I am not getting what you are saying, what is barplot tem and barplot pre. ggplot is based on layer wise representation of geometry, you just cant move a geometry unless you change its value

Comment: In fact, I would like to add an axis y on the right of my graph to have the number of species (thanks to my column nb species) and superimpose the points over the bar plots.

Comment: @Elodie P. Add a separate question or read and try http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html